# How do I use a parameter in the Where clause of a SQL statement used in a Crystal Report?

Tags: sql, postgresql, crystal-reports

I have a SQL statement I'd like to use in a Crystal Report (Crystal Reports 2016).  Here is the `Where` clause of the statement:

```
WHERE
    DV_Inventory.Recv_Order_ID IN (SELECT DV_Order.ID 
                                   FROM DV_Order 
                                   WHERE DV_Order.Vendor_ID IN (SELECT  DV_Business_Partner.ID 
                                                                FROM DV_Business_Partner  
                                                                WHERE DV_Business_Partner.BillingID = '500335')) 
    AND DV_Inventory.Ship_ts isnull 
    AND (DV_Inventory.Qty_Available + DV_Inventory.Qty_Allocated + DV_Inventory.Qty_Hold + DV_Inventory.Qty_Quarantine + DV_Inventory.Qty_Damaged) > 0
```

The report works fine with that `WHERE` clause. However, when I change it to prompt for the billing ID,

```
WHERE 
    DV_Inventory.Recv_Order_ID IN (SELECT DV_Order.ID 
                                   FROM DV_Order 
                                   WHERE DV_Order.Vendor_ID IN (SELECT DV_Business_Partner.ID 
                                                                FROM DV_Business_Partner 
                                                                WHERE DV_Business_Partner.BillingID = ? ...
```

I get the following error:

> 7002:Parameters exist but IPD isn't set. Please call SQLDescribeParam() Database Vendor Code 32

I can run the statement from DBVisualizer without any problems, but I can't get it to work in Crystal Reports.

Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong? This is a PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL Expression Field may not be what you actually need.  Typically SQL Expression Fields are used to look up scalar values with simple queries.  Parameter Fields, Formula Fields, and other objects that are not part of the dataset returned by the Database Expert are considered out of scope to the best of my knowledge.

However, there is another way!  Crystal Report support SQL Commands through the Database Expert.  These commands can have Command Parameters defined that allow you prompt a user for input.  SQL Commands also allow you to use more complex SQL queries with less impact upon the performance of your report.

To create a SQL Command, open Database Expert.  Under "My Connections" you will have a list of all the databases you can connect to.  Expand the database you are using for the report and it will list all of the objects within that database.  The top most item on the list should be "Add Command".